# Prism PopupWindowAction with viewmodel created using dependency injection

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, unity-container, prism

I have created a "popup" window which is being displayed using a PopupWindowAction as per the Prism documentation.  The view is loading just fine, but the ViewModel is not.  All the examples I can find just have a simple ViewModel being created in the code behind for the view.  My ViewModel needs to be constructed by unity so that dependencies can be injected, but this is being bypassed because the view is being declared in the xaml:

```
<prism:InteractionRequestTrigger SourceObject="{Binding CustomViewRequest, Mode=OneWay}">
    <prism:PopupWindowAction>
        <prism:PopupWindowAction.WindowContent>
            <views:CustomView />
        </prism:PopupWindowAction.WindowContent>
    </prism:PopupWindowAction>
</prism:InteractionRequestTrigger>
```

I have a partial workaround which is to embed a ContentControl (with a region) within the PopupWindowAction.WindowContent. That works in that when I load the view into the region, the ViewModel is created for me.  However, each time the Window appears, it is the same size as the total desktop space across all displays.

I was thinking I could implement some code to set the starting position and dimensions of the popup, but I don't have access to the Window because that is being created for me in the PopupWindowAction. I don't want to restrict the size of the underlying ContentControl or View, otherwise the user won't be able to adjust the window size. Plus, that just feels like a workaround!

So how can I get the PopupWindowAction to load the ViewModel using dependency injection? Or if that is not straightforward, how can can access to the Window dimensions and bind them to the viewmodel associated with the view in the ContentControl?

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same need and was able to get it working with a custom derived PopupWindowAction, to allow its WindowContent to be composed. According to the Prism doc [Unity doesn't support the TryResolve extension method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921140%28v=pandp.40%29.aspx#IServiceLocator), but if you are more familiar with Unity there may be an alternative way to do the TryResolve part that would work in Unity.

So I defined a ComposablePopupWindowAction that adds a WindowContentType dependency property. Then I overrode the Invoke method, to use the service locator to get an instance of the WindowContentType if it is defined.

```
// a popupWindowAction that allows the DI to compose its view
public class ComposablePopupWindowAction : PopupWindowAction
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty WindowContentTypeProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
            "WindowContentType",
            typeof(Type),
            typeof(ComposablePopupWindowAction),
            new PropertyMetadata(null),
            v => {
                Type type = v as Type;
                Type frameworkElementType = typeof(FrameworkElement);
                // either this is not specified, or if it is then it needs to be a FrameworkElement
                return (v == null) || type.IsSubclassOf(frameworkElementType) || (type == frameworkElementType);
            }
        );

    public Type WindowContentType
    {
        get { return (Type)GetValue(WindowContentTypeProperty); }
        set { SetValue(WindowContentTypeProperty, value); }
    }

    protected override void Invoke(object parameter)
    {
        ConfigureWindowContent();

        base.Invoke(parameter);
    }

    protected void ConfigureWindowContent()
    {
        // configure the windowContent if not specified, but a type was
        if ((this.WindowContentType != null) && (this.WindowContent == null))
        {
            // this doesn't appear to be supported in Unity so might need slightly different logic here?
            var view = ServiceLocator.Current.TryResolve(this.WindowContentType);
            // if can't get thedesired type then base will use the notification
            if ((view != null) && (view.GetType() == this.WindowContentType))
            {
                this.WindowContent = view as FrameworkElement;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then do the interactionRequestTrigger as normal, and specify the view type for the WindowContentType property:

```
<prism:InteractionRequestTrigger SourceObject="{Binding ConfigurationPopupRequest, Mode=OneWay}">
  <inf:ComposablePopupWindowAction IsModal="True" CenterOverAssociatedObject="True" WindowContentType="{x:Type analysis:ConfigurationPopupView}" />
</prism:InteractionRequestTrigger>
```

Comment: For people reading this in 2018+...
For prism 6.3 (maybe earlier) it seems that PopupWindowAction.WindowContentType should do the same thing as the code above